# Cannot resolve symbol 'annotations' about openapi v3

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

when I using the swagger v3 import like this:

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.Operation;
```

the Intellij Idea shows that:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'annotations'
```

I have already add the openapi v3 plugin in the build.gradle:

```
id "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin" version "1.3.4"
```

and apply it like this:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin'
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed it? I also added this dependencies:

```
api "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `annotations` symbol cannot be resolved when using the `org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin` plugin in a Spring Boot project may be caused by a few different issues:

1. The `springdoc-openapi-data-rest` dependency may not be included in
   your project's classpath. This dependency is required for the
   `org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin` plugin to work properly, and
   provides the necessary annotations that are used to generate the
   OpenAPI documentation. Make sure that this dependency is included in
   your project's build file (e.g. `build.gradle)`.
2. You may be using an older version of the
   `org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin plugin` that is not compatible
   with the version of Spring Boot that you are using. Make sure that
   you are using a version of the plugin that is compatible with your
   version of Spring Boot. You can check the plugin's documentation to
   see which versions of Spring Boot are supported.
3. There may be a conflict with another library or plugin in your
   project that is causing the `annotations` symbol to be unresolved. Try
   resolving any other library conflicts or errors that you may be
   encountering, as this may help to fix the `annotations` symbol issue.